# SQL - query timing out when pulling records for most recent date with a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to pull values for the most recent date (COMPUTE_DAY) in a very large dataset - this seems to be a frequently asked question, with the most common solution to be using a subquery on the same table.  Unfortunately, my query is timing out every time I try that. The table is partitioned on two columns, REGION and COMPUTE_DAY, with primary keys REGION, COMPUTE_DAY and PLAN_UUID.  Are there any ways I can make this query more efficient?

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash(ipp,ipp2) */ 
ipp.COMPUTE_DAY,
ipp.ITEM,
ipp.MANUFACTURER,
ipp.ORDER_DATE,
ipp.CARTON,
sum(ipp.TARGET_INVENTORY) as 1,
sum(ipp.CURRENT_INVENTORY) as 2,
sum(ipp.DEMAND) as 3,
sum(ipp.ORDERS) as 4,
sum(ipp.SHIPMENTS) as 5,
sum(ipp.QUANTITY) as 6,

FROM 
table ipp

WHERE
ipp.REGION = 1
AND ipp.COMPUTE_DAY = (select max(ipp2.COMPUTE_DAY) from O_IP_PLANS ipp2 where ipp2.REGION_ID = 1 AND ipp2.COMPUTE_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYY/MM/DD}','YYYY/MM/DD')-7 AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYY/MM/DD}','YYYY/MM/DD') AND ipp2.PLAN_UUID = ipp.PLAN_UUID) 
AND ipp.GROUP_ID = 121
AND ipp.IOG = 1
AND ipp.INTENT = 'YES'

GROUP BY ipp.COMPUTE_DAY,
ipp.ITEM,
ipp.MANUFACTURER,
ipp.ORDER_DATE,
ipp.CARTON;
```

Comment: Did you check the explain plan ?

Comment: The explain plan shows no errors unfortunately.

Comment: How many rows are in the two tables and how many rows are returned by the query?  If the query is returning a large percentage of data then it might be faster to calculate all the max COMPUTE_DAY per PLAN_UUID, and then join that inline view with ipp, and look for HASH JOIN operations in the execution plan.  If it's a small number, then your existing query might be OK, except you'd want to remove the USE_HASH hint, and look at the explain plan and hope to see a NESTED LOOP operation.  Either way, it might help to add a text version of the explain plan to the question.

Comment: The explain plan never shows erors, this is an optimalization tool, just generate the explain plan of the query and append to the question, we need to examine this plan to know how to optimize the query. First run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query....` then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )` and append a result of last query to the question.